# mongodb - mapReduce() scope - Undefined values are converted into null values

Tags: mongodb, null, mapreduce, undefined

If I put a variable with an undefined value into the "scope" parameter of mapReduce(), then the map function will receive the variable with a null value (instead of the undefined value).  Is that correct?

For example (javascript skeleton for the "mongo" command):

```
db.mycol.mapReduce(
                        f_map,
                        f_reduce,
                        {
                            scope: { myvar:   undefined}
                        }
                  );

function f_map()
{
    print("myvar: " + myvar);
}
```

That will print "myvar: null" (instead of "myvar: undefined") into the server log (into the replicaset member log). Are undefined values converted automatically to null values when passing through mapReduce()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `undefined` values get translated into `null` values in mongodb's [v8 engine](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/3ae747331fc37e7826f6cd20088bee76b3a7bb00/src/mongo/scripting/engine_v8.cpp#L1410).

The reason for this is to keep backwards compatibility with the older Spider Monkey JS engine and not break existing code that relied on that behaviour.